# How to save div and its content as an image on the server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, canvas

Actually I am developing a customizable mugs, t-shirts web application. So when user make any changes in the design i want to capture the whole div and want to save it on the server as an image. I googled it but I end up with nothing. Everyone is saying use CANVAS. But I am adding elements using jquery in the div. So i don't know how to change it to canvas.

My Mark Up

```
<div id="imgs" style="background-color:#222222; color:#fff; width:300px; height:200px">
 // Dynamic Images //Dynamic Content
</div>
```

I want to save this div as an Image.

Here is my the link of my 
[customizable printing website](http://www.jholo.com/Customize.php5?desID=1)

Please help me. Thanks

Comment: You can try to send all the parameters to the server and try to recreate the image on the server side

Comment: @ekhaled that will be my last option. If there will be no way to achieve what i want then i have to do it by your and mine way...

Comment: Browser Security Restrictions will prevent all but the most extreme efforts to convert a browser window into an image on the client-side. My 2-cents: Send the html and CSS info back to the server.

Answer (score -1):

There's no real EASY way to do this.
However, if you're adventurous...
* Create a Windows Forms application
* Embed a browser in the application and have it browse to a URL that contains your div
* Have the application take a screenshot of itself.
* Save it to disk.

Then when the user makes changes, have your server open up the Win Forms application that you created in a separate process.